# How to make page link in php program like this?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

For instance, in tumblr.com, the page link will be like `tumblr.com/dashboard/x`, and `x` means page number.

In php, i used to set page like `/?page=x`.

I am wondering that how to make it working like `tumblr.com`?

I do believe it's not a path that php created.

Comment: Try .htaccess, url re-writting techniques

Comment: Do a search on this site for "URL rewriting PHP" or "routing PHP". Usually, Apache's `mod_rewrite` is involved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I give each registered user their own url using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706935/how-do-i-give-each-registered-user-their-own-url-using-php)

Answer (score 2):

This is called URL rewriting and can be achieved with Apache's mod_rewrite for example : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 1):

here you apache rewrite mode will take care of this you have to add the rewrite rules in the `.htaccess` file

```
# enable apache morRewrite module #
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule index([0-9]*).ht(m?ml?)$ ?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And you url will look like `www.example.com/index12.html`
The `12` after index in the above url will treat as `?page=12`

Hope it makes sense

Comment: Thank you for answering this, but here are some question for your comment.
They look like regular expression.
Is (m?ml?) could be (ml?)?

Comment: yes it coud be html or htm you can change it to as wish like `index12.aspx` or what ever you want