# Generating a html page using php

Tags: php, html

So I have this question after browsing freelancer.com.
What it(freelancer) does is, that whenever a new user registers..it automatically generates a html page for that user.
For example, the user's username is joshm, then freelancer would generate www.domain.com/u/joshm.html , not only this page is generated, but also content is dynamically fetched in this .html page.

Using this technique is better than using www.domain.com/users.php?id=1 (which is prone to XSS/SQL Injection attacks).

My question is, how does this page get generated? and how is the information dynamically fetched to this HTML page ?

Thanks.

Comment: *"Using this technique is better than using www.domain.com/users.php?id=1 (which is prone to XSS/SQL Injection attacks)."* — Wrong. User input is user input. This is no less vulnerable to XSS or SQL Injection then any other way to get data from the user. You must sanitise/escape at the data format boundary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I give each registered user their own url using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706935/how-do-i-give-each-registered-user-their-own-url-using-php)

Comment: Look up `mod_rewrite`, those html pages are not static html files.

Comment: It's a rewrite engine, both of those addresses can point to the exactly same page.

Comment: I don't see why this question is invalid or has downvotes. The OP makes assumptions which are wrong, but that doesn't mean the question itself is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Using this technique is better than using www.domain.com/users.php?id=1 (which is prone to XSS/SQL Injection attacks).

Both techniques are equally vulnerable to whatever vulnerability you subject them to if you don't know what you're doing. Using a query string is not any more unsafe.

Moreover, `/u/joshm.html` is very likely just a "mask". The page still gets processed dynamically with database queries and all, being just as vulnerable as `users.php?name=joshm`. A URL is not the same as a file. Just because the URL says "joshm.html" does not in any way mean there's a file of that name physically on the harddisk anywhere. The web server can answer requests for this URL in any way it pleases, it doesn't have to use a file on disk. The web server is a program that listens on port 80 and responds to HTTP requests. It has nothing to do with the file system per se. `.html` is a good RESTful way to specify that you want the HTML version of the user joshm's information; it does not mean there's a file of that name.

Look into "URL rewriting" and "pretty URLs" for more about this topic.