# PHP extension for all webpage files?

Tags: php, filenames

I was reading PHP Solutions by David Powers and came across this:

> There is no problem mixing .html and .php pages in the same website.
>   However, PHP code will be processed only in files that have the .php
>   filename extension, so it's a good idea to give the same extension to
>   all your pages, even if they don't all contain dynamic features. That
>   way, you have the flexibility to add PHP to pages without breaking
>   existing links or losing search engine rankings.

So is naming all your webpage files with the `.php` extension the best practice? Also, how would not doing so lose search engine rankings?

Comment: I do not think that search Engine will have trouble with a php page.

Comment: You can get PHP to be processed in files with `.html` endings. A search engine won't be bothered if you use `.php` or `.html` as a file ending

Comment: It would break links and change search engine rankings because you would have to change .html to .php if you want to use PHP in a file, meaning the .html link is no longer valid.

Comment: Do not 'close' your question by deleting the text, simply click the close, or delete, link below the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it is good practice to keep your PHP and HTML in seperated files by using template engines(example smarty: http://www.smarty.net/). So you can make easly system and design changes.

And mod_rewrite method is good thing, to hide the fact, that you are using PHP. Example, you can make your URLs at beginning with GET method: domain.com/index.php?page=help

With mod_rewrite you can change that URL to this: domain.com/help

It makes your URLs look nice and short.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping implementation details (such as the fact you are using PHP) out of your URLs as much as possible is best practise.

You can achieve this with mod_rewrite, [ScriptAlias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16706998/19068), or configuring the server to recognise PHP in `.html` files.

Answer (score 1):

If you intent to have any kind of php code in your website, using .php for all files from the beginning is indeed the best practice.

An example to clarify the last sentence; 
You have created your site using .html files, search engines indexed them. When you decide to change .html to .php search engines cannot find the previously indexed .html files anymore which can be bad.

Answer (score 0):

1. It makes sense not to mix .html and .php files on the same site, for exactly the reason he states. I guess that makes it a best practice.
2. If you have a faq.html page and you then make it dynamic/database driven, it would need to be renamed to faq.php and search engines wouldn't know that the one file has replaced the other file (unless you specify a redirect on your website) so you could lose search engine rankings on that page - as it's just disappeared from the search engine's point of view.