# How can I fetch information from database without using $ _GET and showing information in page

Tags: php

*I'm a new php programmer.*

For example, Facebook's Profile users will show the way

**www.facebook.com/oneUser**

But I do not know how to do it and I can use the variable **$ _GET** to do this

*For example*

**www.example.com?user_id=110**

how can I like facebook or a lot of other sites do it without using $_ GET
for example:
**www.example.com/110**

Comment: Use URL rewriting https://www.google.com/search?q=apache+urlrewritting

Comment: Look up pretty urls or slug urls

Comment: Check above comments, and to clarify - they use $_GET aswell, just url looks different

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I give each registered user their own url using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706935/how-do-i-give-each-registered-user-their-own-url-using-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use URL rewriting

I have found this article helpful for Apache: http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

And Microsofts resource for IIS url rewriting: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

If you create your rules for Apache you can easily import them into IIS so go that way if you are undecided :)

Comment: No problemo. If this answer resolves your problem don't forget to give it the magical green tick to let others know.